# Is there some way to extract only 2 digit numeric or decimal from a paatern in python?

Tags: python, regex

In the text line below, I wanted to extract only 13.5 or 13 (in case decimal is not there in the text)  using regex in python. Example of text is given below. OPlease help

"This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only ever appears in 960/700 the hole of a donut. 13.5/10 (it can be 13/10 also)"

Result must be 13 if text have 13/10 or 13.5 if text has 13.5/10.

I will really appreciate our help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the rule that tells you what part of the text you want, *exactly*? For example, can something other than `10` appear after the `/`? Why do you need to extract this, and what problem will you solve with the result?

Comment: Hi Karl, Sorry for not mentioning in detail. Actually this is data from twitter in which two-digit/two-digit number shows the rating and it be like 13.5/10, 13.5/15, 15/20. Although numerator greater than denominator does not make sense, but  I am looking to extract two digit numerator in this case. while three-digit/three-digit is non essential and is not required. I am new to python, so I choose this data set for data wrangling purposes. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will match the expected output:

```
import re

txt = "This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only ever appears in 960/700 the hole of a donut. 13.5/10 (it can be 13/10 also)"

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}.?\d?)/\d{2}\s')

res = re.finditer(pattern, txt)

for r in res:
    print(r.group(1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jose for helping out. How to solve this issue if in place of 10 there is any other 2 digit number. Eg - 13.5/10, 26/20. Then how can I extract only two digit numeric or decimal in this case? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: For that, use the following pattern r'(\d{1,2}.?\d?)/\d{2}\s'